# Unable to create PHP project in NetBeans 8.2 and Apache 11 w/ JDK 8u221 (hanging at 40%)

Tags: java, php, netbeans

I have a new Windows 10 laptop and installed NetBeans 8.2 on it. I attempted to create a PHP project with existing sources, but this kept getting stuck at 40%. Trying again a number of times, rebooting, and removing and reinstalling NetBeans didn't help.

I need this project to work. So I removed NetBeans 8.2 and installed Apache NetBeans 11. I had the same problem when creating the project. Progress was stuck at 40% and there was a Java error (java.lang.NullPointerException) in the IDE log.

Googling the issue seemed to indicate I should try installing the JDK manually and setting its location in /etc/netbeans.conf. I did this and reopened Apache NetBeans. Attempting to create the project results in the same problem (progress stuck forever at 40%) and apparently the same IDE log:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>Log Session: Tuesday, October 1, 2019 4:55:39 PM BST
>System Info: 
  Product Version         = Apache NetBeans IDE 11.0 (Build incubator-netbeans-release-404-on-20190319)
  Operating System        = Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.8.0_221; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.221-b11; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_221-b11
  Java Home               = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre
  System Locale; Encoding = en_GB (nb); Cp1252
  Home Directory          = C:\Users\44780
  Current Directory       = C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\bin
  User Directory          = C:\Users\44780\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.0
  Cache Directory         = C:\Users\44780\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.0
  Installation            = C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\nb
                            C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\ergonomics
                            C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\ide
                            C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\extide
                            C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\java
                            C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\apisupport
                            C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\webcommon
                            C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\websvccommon
                            C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\enterprise
                            C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\profiler
                            C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\php
                            C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\harness
                            C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\groovy
                            C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\javafx
                            C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\classes;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar
  Application Classpath   = C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\platform\lib\boot.jar;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\platform\lib\org-openide-modules.jar;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\platform\lib\org-openide-util-lookup.jar;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\platform\lib\org-openide-util-ui.jar;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\platform\lib\org-openide-util.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\lib\dt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\lib\tools.jar
  Startup Classpath       = C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\platform\core\asm-all-5.0.1.jar;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\platform\core\core-base.jar;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\platform\core\core.jar;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\platform\core\org-netbeans-libs-asm.jar;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\platform\core\org-openide-filesystems-compat8.jar;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\platform\core\org-openide-filesystems.jar;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\nb\core\org-netbeans-upgrader.jar;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\nb\core\locale\core_nb.jar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.netbinox]: Install area set to file:/C:/Users/44780/Documents/Tools/incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin/netbeans/
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting which is deprecated.
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.ide.kit, org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.structure which is deprecated.
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in Services/MIMEResolver/ marked with the position attribute: [org-netbeans-modules-gradle-GradleDataObject-Extension.xml], but some are: [org-openide-loaders-DataLoaderPool$InstanceLoaderSystem-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-core-startup-layers-SystemFileSystem-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-java-JavaDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-java-ClassDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-image-ImageDataObject-serialVersionUID-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-image-ImageDataObject-IMAGE_ICON_BASE-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-image-ImageDataObject-openSupport-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-image-ImageDataObject-printSupport-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-properties-PropertiesDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-javascript-gulp-file-Gulpfile-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-javascript-grunt-file-Gruntfile-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-javascript2-editor-JsonLanguage-createMultiViewEditorElement-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-php-twig-editor-TwigDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-javascript-karma-util-KarmaUtils-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-PackageJson-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-javascript-bower-file-BowerJson-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-javascript-bower-file-BowerrcJson-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-languages-manifest-MfDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-languages-apacheconf-ApacheConfDataObject-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-javascript-jstestdriver-JSTestDriverSupport-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-languages-ini-IniDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-languages-neon-NeonDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-form-FormDataLoader-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-core-ide-ServiceTabProcessor-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-testng-ui-wizards-TestNGSuiteDataObject-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-css-editor-CssProjectSupport-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-languages-diff-DiffDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-javascript2-editor-JsLanguage-createMultiViewEditorElement-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-javascript2-jade-editor-JadeLanguage-createMultiViewEditorElement-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-javascript2-editor-JsonLanguage-createMultiViewEditorElement-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-db-sql-loader-SQLDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-javawebstart-JnlpDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-persistence-unit-PUDataObject-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-jshell-env-JShellDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-groovy-gsp-GspLanguage-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-languages-yaml-YamlLanguage-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-groovy-editor-api-parser-GroovyLanguage-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-php-editor-index-PHPIndexer-LOG-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-html-HtmlDataObject-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-maven-grammar-POMDataObject-Registration.xml, org-apache-tools-ant-module-loader-AntProjectDataObject-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-apisupport-project-layers-LayerDataObject-Namespace.xml, org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-storage-SettingsProvider-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-ddloaders-common-DD2beansDataObject-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-sun-ddloaders-SunDescriptorDataObject-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-url-URLDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-pdf-PDFDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-php-smarty-editor-TplDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-tomcat5-ui-nodes-TomcatInstanceNode-createMultiViewEditorElement-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-web-core-jsploader-JspDataObject-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-web-jsf-JSFConfigDataObject-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-web-struts-StrutsConfigDataObject-Namespace.xml, org-netbeans-modules-spring-beans-loader-SpringXMLConfigDataObject-Namespace.xml, org-netbeans-modules-xsl-XSLDataObject-Namespace.xml, org-netbeans-modules-java-jarloader-JarDataObject-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-xml-jaxb-JAXBWizard-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-lib-editor-codetemplates-storage-CodeTemplatesStorage-Namespace.xml, org-netbeans-modules-editor-macros-storage-MacrosStorage-Namespace.xml, mimeresolver-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-web-beans-BeansDataObject-Namespace.xml, org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-sun-ide-sunresources-resourcesloader-SunResourceDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-profiler-oql-language-OQLLanguageProvider-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-dbschema-jdbcimpl-DBschemaDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-css-prep-editor-less-LessCslLanguage-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-css-prep-editor-scss-ScssCslLanguage-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-persistence-jpqleditor-ui-JPQLEditorTopComponent-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-php-latte-LatteDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-profiler-snaptracer-impl-NpssDataObject-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-java-hints-declarative-HintDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-javafx2-editor-fxml-FXMLDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-form-palette-PaletteItemDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-xml-XMLDataObject-MIME_PLAIN_XML-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-xml-DTDDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-xml-EntityDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-xml-XMLDataObject-MIME_XSD_XML-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-libs-freemarker-FreemarkerFactory-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-apisupport-project-layers-LayerDataObject-Registration.xml, resources-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-profiler-ui-NpsDataObject-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-profiler-ui-HprofDataObject-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-NodeMimeResolver-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-xml-XMLDataObject-Registration.xml, org-netbeans-modules-java-hints-declarative-test-DeclarativeHintsTestDataObject-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-debugger-jpda-truffle-mime-LanguageResolvers-SimpleLanguage-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-debugger-jpda-truffle-mime-LanguageResolvers-R-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-debugger-jpda-truffle-mime-LanguageResolvers-Ruby-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-debugger-jpda-truffle-mime-LanguageResolvers-Python-Extension.xml, org-netbeans-modules-defaults-mime-wav.xml]
WARNING [null]: Last record repeated 2 more times.
INFO [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]: Turning on modules:
    org.openide.util.lookup [8.37.1 incubator-netbeans-release-404-on-20190319]
    org.openide.util [9.11.1 incubator-netbeans-release-404-on-20190319]
    org.openide.util.ui [9.12.1 incubator-netbeans-release-404-on-20190319]
    org.openide.modules [7.52.1 incubator-netbeans-release-404-on-20190319]
<snip due to character limit>
    com.jcraft.jzlib [1.0.7 1.0.7]
    com.googlecode.javaewah.JavaEWAH [0.7.9 0.7.9]
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.osgi@3.9.1.v20140110-1610 started
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy resolver: Windows
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.windows.WindowsNetworkProxy]: Windows system proxy resolver: auto detect
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy reloading succeeded.
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy - mode: direct
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy: fell to default (correct if direct mode went before)
Diagnostic information
Input arguments:
    -Dnetbeans.importclass=org.netbeans.upgrade.AutoUpgrade
    -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
    -Xss2m
    -Dnetbeans.logger.console=true
    -Djdk.gtk.version=2.2
    -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true
    -Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true
    -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
    -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true
    -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true
    -Dplugin.manager.check.updates=false
    -Dnetbeans.extbrowser.manual_chrome_plugin_install=yes
    --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-modules=jdk.jshell
    --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.beans.editors=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.javadoc/com.sun.tools.javadoc.main=ALL-UNNAMED
    -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
    -Djdk.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221
    -Dnetbeans.home=C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\platform
    -Dnetbeans.user=C:\Users\44780\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.0
    -Dnetbeans.default_userdir_root=C:\Users\44780\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans
    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
    -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\44780\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.0\var\log\heapdump.hprof
    -Dsun.awt.keepWorkingSetOnMinimize=true
    -Dnetbeans.dirs=C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\nb;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\ergonomics;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\ide;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\extide;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\java;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\apisupport;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\webcommon;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\websvccommon;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\enterprise;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\mobility;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\profiler;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\python;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\php;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\identity;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\harness;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\cnd;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\cndext;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\dlight;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\groovy;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\extra;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\javacard;C:\Users\44780\Documents\Tools\incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin\netbeans\javafx
    exit
Compiler: HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
Heap memory usage: initial 126.0MB maximum 1788.5MB
Non heap memory usage: initial 2.4MB maximum -1b
Garbage collector: PS Scavenge (Collections=8 Total time spent=0s)
Garbage collector: PS MarkSweep (Collections=2 Total time spent=0s)
Classes: loaded=6631 total loaded=6631 unloaded 0
INFO [org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.DiagnosticTask]: Total memory 8,437,022,720
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Found same position 400 for both Templates/Project/AntJava/J2EE and Templates/Project/AntJava/j2sefreeform.xml
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Found same position 200 for both Templates/Project/AntJava/Web and Templates/Project/AntJava/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-ui-wizards-NewJ2SEProjectWizardIterator-library
INFO [org.openide.WizardDescriptor]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.netbeans.modules.php.project.ui.wizards.NewPhpProjectWizardIterator.current(NewPhpProjectWizardIterator.java:351)
    at org.netbeans.modules.php.project.ui.wizards.NewPhpProjectWizardIterator.uninitialize(NewPhpProjectWizardIterator.java:170)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard$InstantiatingIteratorBridge.uninitialize(TemplateWizard.java:1054)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.uninitialize(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:215)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.uninitialize(TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.java:131)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callUninitialize(WizardDescriptor.java:1541)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.resetWizardOpen(WizardDescriptor.java:1383)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.resetWizard(WizardDescriptor.java:1362)
[catch] at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.setValueOpen(WizardDescriptor.java:1346)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.setValue(WizardDescriptor.java:1334)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter$ButtonListener.actionPerformed(NbPresenter.java:1367)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.windowClosing(NbPresenter.java:1257)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowClosing(AWTEventMulticaster.java:349)
    at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2054)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.processWindowEvent(JDialog.java:683)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2013)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:136)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.superShow(NbPresenter.java:1060)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.doShow(NbPresenter.java:1110)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.run(NbPresenter.java:1082)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.run(NbPresenter.java:105)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.NbMutexEventProvider$Event.doEventAccess(NbMutexEventProvider.java:115)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.NbMutexEventProvider$Event.readAccess(NbMutexEventProvider.java:75)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.LazyMutexImplementation.readAccess(LazyMutexImplementation.java:71)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:193)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.show(NbPresenter.java:1067)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.DialogDisplayerImpl$1AWTQuery.showDialog(DialogDisplayerImpl.java:241)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.DialogDisplayerImpl$1AWTQuery.run(DialogDisplayerImpl.java:167)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:136)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.LayersBridge]: Invalid shortcut: org.openide.loaders.XMLDataObject@69261669[MultiFileObject@4d416d96[Actions/Help/master-help.xml]]
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.LayersBridge]: Invalid shortcut: org.openide.loaders.BrokenDataShadow@203a369e[MultiFileObject@6bfeb124[Keymaps/NetBeans/D-BACK_QUOTE.shadow]]
WARNING [null]: Last record repeated again.
```

I tried the same steps on another machine. Creating the project works fine there. Both machines have Apache NetBeans 11 and JDK 8u221. Both have the JDK path set in netbeans.conf. The first one can't create a project; the second one can.

Unfortunately this really has to work on the machine that is hanging at 40%. That machine is a new work laptop which is being used by a remote worker. The worker has to be able to create a PHP project with existing sources in order to edit the company website.

Is the error message telling me anything useful? What should I try next?

Comment: The older release was the version the employer supported. As I described above, the same problem happens in V11 on that machine, and the log text is from V11.

Comment: I have tried NetBeans 10 tonight and the same issue occurs. Stuck on 40% and there is a java.lang.NullPointerException in the IDE log as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an amswer; it's just some interim suggestions, and a request for further information which is too big to post as a comment.

- Don't use NetBeans 11.0, use the latest version, [NetBeans 11.1 instead](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb111/nb111.html).
- You definitely don't need to uninstall other versions of NetBeans, though it is prudent to only run one version at a time.
- It looks like you have activated PHP, but have you tried to create a trivial PHP project from scratch to verify that everything is installed correctly? If not:

  1. First, if you haven't already done so, you need to specify a PHP interpreter to NetBeans: **Tools > Options > PHP** tab, then click the **Browse...** button for the **PHP interpreter** field, and navigate to your installation of `php.exe`. After that your screen should look similar to the screen shot shown below.

     [image: PHPconfiguration]
  2. Next, create a simple "*Hello world*" PHP application: **File > New Project > PHP > PHP Application** (N.B. not **PHP Application with Existing Sources**). Run that project. Does that work? If not, describe the problem, because that should work fine.
- If you can create and run a trivial PHP project then repeat your import "*with Existing Sources*" to see if the problem persists.
- If it does the next thing to try is to import a second PHP project which is trivial. That will determine whether the issue is general, or specific to the project in the OP. Either way, update your question to replace your listing of the IDE Log for NetBeans 11.0 with one for NetBeans 11.1. To be clear, I'm not suggesting that there is a problem with 11.0, but there is no reason not to use the latest version of NetBeans, unless you face some employer restriction.
- As a separate matter, one other thing you can try is to compare the IDE log for the machine where everything works with the one where you have problems, checking for potentially significant differences with your two NetBeans installations. A file comparison tool would help with that.

If you get stuck on anything, also see https://php.tutorials24x7.com/blog/how-to-install-netbeans-11-for-php-on-windows for general instructions on getting PHP set up on NetBeans.

What's the updated status if you tried the steps described above?

Comment: Thank you! The steps above helped us discover the root of the problem. We were able to create a trivial PHP project, but we could not create one with existing sources of any kind, no matter how trivial. The issue seemed to come down to McAfee, which had come installed on the laptop (expired trial version). We removed it, set the system to use Windows Defender anti-virus, applied all the updates to Windows Defender, and tried again. The project took several minutes to create but ultimately it succeeded and now it works. Accepting this answer since it got us far enough to reach resolution.

Comment: I've been leery of updating NB because I have a large & complex Java SE project now running well on 11. I'm reconsidering this issue now because I want to also do some Web app development  which apparently can't be done with 11 because the needed plugins won't load. Based on answers in this thread, it seems there should be no major problems if I switch from NB 11 to the latest version. Is that right?

Comment: @EdS With NetBeans you can have your cake and eat it too. Rather than steeling yourself for a potentially problematic upgrade, why not just leave your existing installation of NetBeans untouched, and install a newer version of NetBeans as well. The two instances can happily coexist, and even run concurrently, without causing any problems (as long as you don't share a project between them). So first download and install NetBeans 13, and verify that all is well with some copies/clones of some projects. Next, if everything looks good, develop/deploy your existing projects on NetBeans 13...

Comment: ...Finally, once everything looks good on NetBeans 13 you can safely delete your older NetBeans 11 installation. So rather than doing an all-or-nothing upgrade you can gradually drift across to the newer version of NetBeans, project by project.

Comment: @skomisa I downloaded NetBeans 13 installer. Tried to do the recommended validation bit but was thoroughly baffled by the Apache instructions. Then I ran NB 13 and opened my big projects, inadvertently overlooking your "verify that all is well with some copies/clones of some projects " advice. Fearlessly, I hit the Clean & Build and lo and behold it completed with some warnings but no errors, and the app runs just fine. Have yet to try creating a Web app.

Comment: @EdS Victory goes to the brave! The checksum validation varies by O/S. On the [NetBeans 13 download page](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb13/nb13.html) click the **SHA-512** link (yes, it is a link!) next to the installer you downloaded. The sha-512 checksum, will be displayed on as new page. Use an appropriate utility (e.g. [certutil on Windows](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/finding-checksum-values-in-windows-10/dbc3c569-4b5a-4967-8810-c25255cdc1fd)) to verify that the checksum for your download matches that shown on the NetBeans website.